# How to iterate object in ejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Good day! I'm a beginner at Node.js. I have a problem with an iterating object on ejs. I've used the book object to retrieve all data from DB and tried to pass it using res.locals. I will use the object to display the book information on the front-end. I tried several ways to iterate object that I've stored on middleware and I'm stuck on it (such as iterating the books by its length and using forEach).

Middleware:

```
let book = await Book.find({});
res.locals.book = {book};
next();
```

EJS:

```
<%if (book){%>
    <%for (var result in book){%>
    <li><%=book%></li> 
    <li><%=result%>:<%=book[result]%></li>    
<%}%>
```

Result:

[image]

Is there another way to iterate and display it? Tyia!

Comment: Are you trying to display the Title of the book?

Comment: I'm trying to display all of the data of DB such as title, author, price, and etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<%if (book){%>
<%for (var result in book){%>
    <li>genre :<ul><%=for(genres in book[result].genre) {%>
        <li><%=book[result].genre[genres]%></li>
<%}%>
     </ul>
    </li>    
<li>title:<%=book[result].title %></li>
<li>copy:<%=book[result].copy %></li>
<li>cover:<%=book[result].cover %></li>
<li>author:<%=book[result].author %></li>
<li>price:<%=book[result].price %></li>
<li>description:<%=book[result].description %></li>
<li>language:<%=book[result].language %></li>
<li>release date:<%=book[result].release_date %></li>
<li>favorites:<%=book[result].favorites %></li>

<%}%>
```

i hope this  will helpful to you

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it didn't display the content of DB. Just a list of title, copy, cover, etc.